# visual studio 2013 professional can I mock tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am looking at getting vs 2013 professional, looking at this comparison chart,

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs

it doesn't look like I can use fakes to mock tests?

are there any other tools I can use? It looks like it is only included in ultimate and premium?

Thanks

Comment: You can write tests even in Pro version and you can pretty much use anything you like, NUnit, Rhino mocks, MOQ, FakeItEasy

Comment: most of the popular tools don't come from microsoft.

Comment: I know this comment is going to get bashed for asking for opinion.. but in your eyes.. should I just stick with professional edition as opposed to Premium or ultimate?  I am looking at getting the MSDN subscription..  http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/msdn-subscriptions-vs#AdditionalPageSections_1